# How to disable notifications in Guard (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, guard

I can't find how to disable notifications when running Guard 2.4.4 with Ruby 2.5.1 on Linux within byobu (if that makes a difference).

The wiki says to put `notification :off` to disable notifications. If I put it in my `Guardfile`, it has no effect. If I put it in my `~/.guardrc` file, I get a `NoMethodError` for `notification`. If I type `notification :off` at the guard prompt, it says notifications are off, but I still get them to show on every run.

They're annoying because they stay on screen for 10 seconds every time: I can never tell if it's from the latest run or if it's from a couple of runs ago when making small changes. They're fully opaque too so I have to wait for them to clear before I can click button on the area the notifications hide.

Any success in disabling Guard notifications?

Comment: Still have this issue, any luck solving it ?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in 2.4.4, updating to 2.4.6 fixed the issue, and `notification :off` in my `~/.guard.rb` (not `~/.guardrc`, this one is to configure `pry`) is no longer ignored.

Answer (score 0):

After getting here found full description on wiki
https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/System-notifications

```
notification :off
```

is correct, but may also be put in a Guardfile